# How to display a field from SQL database in a message box

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-express

I have this already on VB:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

Try
con.ConnectionString = "Server=SISTEMAS\SQLEXPRESS;Database=UPC;Trusted_Connection=Yes" 'Coneccion a la base de datos'"
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UPC_Table WHERE UPCNumber='" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND Description= '" & TextBox2.Text & "'", con)
Dim numerorecord As Int32 = cmd.ExecuteScalar

If numerorecord > 0 Then
MsgBox("NUMERO DE UPC YA EXISTE")
Else
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UPC_Table (UPCNumber, Description) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')" 'Codigo para insertar UPC del text box a la base de datos'
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MessageBox.Show("UPC Entrado")
End If


Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show("Error..." & ex.Message, "Inserta el Record")
Finally
con.Close()
End Try

End Sub
```

I want in the first message box to bring me a record from SQL. Example:

I they input on the upc textbox upc # 123456 then entered again a message box saying that upc # 123456 belongs to let's say KETCHUP (This coming from the SQL database)

Comment: Better learn how to use parameters to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Obligatory link. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would make a couple of changes to accomplish this:

1) Return only the column you need from the database (in my example change myFieldName to the name of your column)

2) Return an object from the query and check if the object has a value and process accordingly.

The revised code is below.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

        Try
            con.ConnectionString = "Server=SISTEMAS\SQLEXPRESS;Database=UPC;Trusted_Connection=Yes" 'Coneccion a la base de datos'"
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT myFieldName FROM UPC_Table WHERE UPCNumber='" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND Description= '" & TextBox2.Text & "'", con)

            Dim val As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

            If val Is Nothing Then
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO UPC_Table (UPCNumber, Description) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "')" 'Codigo para insertar UPC del text box a la base de datos'
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("UPC Entrado")
            Else
                MsgBox("The UPC is" & val)
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error..." & ex.Message, "Inserta el Record")
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
```